# Como fazer controle de versões com GitLab?

Tags: gitlab

#### Cenário

Tenho uma pasta local (em minha máquina) com todas as pastas e arquivos de **vários projetos**.

Por algumas indicações, escolhi o *GitLab* pois preciso guardar **projetos privados**.

---

#### Dúvidas

- Existe uma ferramenta para "**sincronizar**" toda essa minha estrutura?

  - Essa ferramenta faria **controle de versões**?
- Caso não, existe outra forma ou **não há possibilidade**?

*Agradeço qualquer outra dica importante sobre o GitLab.*

Comment: Quem faz o controle de versão é o git, o GitLab é apenas um gerenciador de repositório de software (ou programas) que é baseado no git.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz então devo usar uma ferramenta git?

Comment: Assim, você vai usar comandos git para controlar as versões do seu código e de uma maneira bem simples, vai "jogar", ou melhor, subir o seu código para o GitLab, por exemplo, onde ele ficará salvo. Dá um olhada nesse curso, https://www.udemy.com/git-e-github-para-iniciantes/, é gratuito e muito bom. Vai te ensinar bastente.

Comment: @JoãoPedroSchmitz opa cara! Bom demais! Vou ver esse curso. Acredito que no lugar do GitLab, está o Github, então é praticamente o mesmo conceito em relação ao git e o restante, correto!?

Comment: Isso mesmo, no lugar do GitLab é o GitHub, mas a ideia por trás é a mesma. O importante mesmo é aprender os comandos do git, que hoje em dia, é quase que um pré-requisito básico para qualquer vaga de emprego.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GitLab já oferece o serviço de controlar versões

Talvez você seja novo no Git e por isso esteja confundindo as coisas, então eu indico que você passe pelo [guia básico e rápido do Git](https://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/index.pt_BR.html).

Em resumo resumido, o Git é o software que você instala localmente para controlar as versões dos seus arquivos localmente. GitLab, GitHub, BitBucket e outros serviços, oferecem um repositório Git na nuvem para você espelhar o seu repositório local, além de outras ferramentas bem bacanas para você organizar e compartilhar o seu trabalho.

Para simplificar, se estiver em um trabalho solo, o seu procedimento no dia-a-dia é alterar o seu código-fonte no seu editor favorito e executar comandos git para atualizar o seu repositório local e depois outros comandos git para enviar essas alterações para o serviço na nuvem que você escolheu.

Existem [diversas opções de ferramentas gráficas](https://git-scm.com/downloads/guis) que você pode usar para executar os comandos git caso não queira fazer isso por linha de comando. Algumas IDEs já tem integração com Git também.